# Visual C++ method for closing webbrowser

Tags: visual-c++, browser, disconnect

I'm looking for a method that disconnects and CLOSES the webbrowser window. 
The code:

```
 webBrowser1->Stop();
```

doesn't work.

It just seems to block an ongoing navigation.

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: You are probably looking for `Quit` method. `Stop` just cancels the current navigation.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that! Is there one?

Comment: Why would I suggest it if [there weren't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752140.aspx)?

Comment: No, I don't think You are that evel, but to be precise I ment how it is called and where could I find it. I don't find the class IWebBrowser2 and the webBrowser1 hasn't got that method, thats why I asked You 4 that. What is HRESULT? I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express Version.

Comment: What is `webBrowser1`? I assumed you were automating a stand-alone instance of Internet Explorer, in which case you would have `Quit` method. But if instead you are hosting a `WebBrowser` control on your form, just close that form.

Comment: If you click on webBrowser on the tool box, the object that appears is automatically called webBrowser1. Of course, if it was the only control on my Form, then Your solution would be right and I wouldn't have asked the question. But there are other elements on the same form and thats why I was looking for a kind of Quit method just for the webBrowser. Meanwhile I've discovered another solution: I open a second form with just the webBrowser on it.